# How to extract calculations using tf-idf

Tags: python, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I used `TfidfVectorizer` to extract TF-IDF but don't know how it calculates the results. When I calculate it manually, I get a different answer, so I want to extract the values ​​that the function calculates in order to learn how it works.

```
data = ['Souvenir shop|Architecture and art|Culture and history', 'Souvenir shop|Resort|Diverse cuisine|Fishing|Folk games|Beautiful scenery', 'Diverse cuisine|Resort|Beautiful scenery']

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have [a look in the scikit documentation at the `attributes` section](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html).

Try this:

```
print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
```

Output

```
{'souvenir': 14,
 'shop': 13,
 'architecture': 1,
 'and': 0,
 'art': 2,
 'culture': 5,
 'history': 10,
 'resort': 11,
 'diverse': 6,
 'cuisine': 4,
 'fishing': 7,
 'folk': 8,
 'games': 9,
 'beautiful': 3,
 'scenery': 12}
```

You get the idf calculations with `print(vectorizer.idf_)`

Output

```
array([1.69314718, 1.69314718, 1.69314718, 1.28768207, 1.28768207,
       1.69314718, 1.28768207, 1.69314718, 1.69314718, 1.69314718,
       1.69314718, 1.28768207, 1.28768207, 1.28768207, 1.28768207])
```

For your case you can do this (with pandas):

```
df_idf = pd.DataFrame(
    vectorizer.idf_, index=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out(), columns=["idf_weights"]
)

display(df_idf)
```

Output

```
             idf_weights
and          1.693147
architecture 1.693147
art          1.693147
beautiful    1.287682
cuisine      1.287682
culture      1.693147
diverse      1.287682
fishing      1.693147
folk         1.693147
games        1.693147
history      1.693147
resort       1.287682
scenery      1.287682
shop         1.287682
souvenir     1.287682
```

Comment: Let me ask, for example, the word "Beautiful" appears twice in two documents of the data set, then in a text the word "beautiful" will have a different tf-idf value (in 2 documents, the word "beautiful" will includes 2 values tf-idf). so how can vectorizer.fit_transform give a specific tf-idf value for the word "beautiful" if I use a vectorizer.transform to compare with the data (I am applying it in content-based filtering)

Comment: I suggest you post this as a new question. I understand that your new question is not about programming per se (the focus of SO) but rather about the inner workings of td-idf and the way the metric is implemented by scikit-learn. Therefore you might be better off posting your question on [Data Science StackExchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).